# Is gold only used for sacrificing?

Tags: ios, sword-of-fargoal

In Sword of Fargoal for the iPhone, you can find gold scattered around the dungeon. There are also various temples where you can sacrifice your gold for experience.

Is gold only used for sacrificing, or is there another use for it?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if mechanics were changed from the older versions of Fargoal to the iPhone port. Also, which tag should we use - `fargoal` or `sword-of-fargoal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the developer, and he said **gold is only used for sacrificing in Fargoal**.

> Currently (like the original game) that's the primary use of gold. Helps you gain levels of experience!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to gaining experience from sacrificing gold you will also gain an Enchanted Weapon +1 for every 1000 x DL of gold sacrificed on a given DL (Dungeon Level). If you want, you can keep returning to the first DL after collecting gold to gain several Enchanted Weapons +1 until you get bored with it.